# Led light - trip breaker

Tags: wiring, led, light

I tried to install an LED light in our pantry to replace an incandescent bulb. It is not hooked to a normal light switch but to a push button on/off with the door open and closing! The breaker remains tripped.
I don’t know what I’m doing wrong!
[image]

Comment: I see a white wire (and black behind it) going *behind* the white wirenuts - it is not a white-striped-black wire and it is not tied in with the blacks.  I am not seeing the problem.   Are you sure these are 120V LEDs and not 12V low voltage types?

Comment: It states it’s a 120 vac, 60 Hz, 20w. So I’m ok there. I have put all the wires together!

Comment: What are the colors of the two wires going to the pushbutton switch? Are those 2 wires seen in this photo?  Why did you select those particular colors?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a white jumper wire connecting the wirenut that joins the white wires with the wirenut that joins the black wires. Assuming that power comes in via one of the black wires, this jumper is allowing power to flow directly to the neutral wires without any load, causing a short circuit. Without further information it is difficult to say how this *should* be wired, but I can say with some certainty that you should remove that white jumper.

Comment: No, he doesn't.  Note my first comment to the question.

Comment: I see your comment, but even after close reinspection it still appears to me that the white jumper enters the wire nut with the rest of the black conductors, along with the black one behind it. So I count 5 conductors entering that wire nut, which is also too many, assuming that the wire is 14AWG.

Comment: I know.  I puzzled on it for awhile. But I'm right. You have to zoom it way in, and a phone won't do.  But the bottom/back of the  wirenut *slightly* overshadows the white wire and black behind it, in a way rhat would be impossible if it entered the nut.  Also to the left of the nut there are a couple pixels of evidence that after going behind the nut, the pair exits the field.